# Why is the while loop is not stoping after the last statement?

Tags: c

In the next program the while loop suppose to stop after the printf in the block is executed:

isn't it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define HOUR 60

int main()

{

    int min, smallThenHour, timeInHour, minLeft;

    printf("please enter time in minutes: \n");

    scanf("%d", &min);

    while (min > 0)

    {
        timeInHour = min/HOUR;
        minLeft = min % HOUR;
        smallThenHour = min < HOUR;

        printf("in %d seconds, there are %d and %d min",min, timeInHour,smallThenHour);
    }

}
```

Would appreciate is someone can tell a c beginner why its not stopping :)

tnx

Comment: You never change `min`, so the condition (`min > 0`) is always true...

Comment: Did you mean to use an `if` instead of a `while`?

Comment: no actually in the exercise it say to use while..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you never change the value of `min` inside the loop body. Once the condition is true, it always remains true.

Comment: so what should i add so it will ask the min again from the user?

Comment: @user1959174: Move the prompt into the loop?

Comment: i want to go out of the loop after the printf and ask from the user the min again, maybe after the printf to add ++min? @Kerrek SB

Comment: got it, thanks. just had to add the scanf statement after the printf in the while block